# Open a filedescriptor specified by a variable

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I would like to open a file descriptor like:

`exec 3> /path/to/file`

where the actual file descriptor number is in a variable:

```
fd=3
exec $fd> /path/to/file
```

Unfortunately this does not work:

```
bash: exec: 3: not found
```

Is there a way to do this with bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `eval`:

```
fd=3
file=/path/to/file

eval "exec $fd> $file"
```

Comment: Uh, that gets messy when I actually want to write stuff into my filedescriptor. But yes, that works. Thanks!